# Mysql -- 2 counts in one query, bad second count result

Tags: mysql, sql

I just inherited a codebase, and there's an existing query that is incorrect. It looks like (genericized tables & columns here):

```
select p.user_id, p.photo_id, p.date, count(p.photo_id) as 'Photos', count(v.photo_id) as 'Views'
from photos p
LEFT OUTER JOIN userviews v on v.user_id = p.user_id and v.photo_id = p.photo_id
where p.photo_id in ( 1,2,3 [...] )
GROUP BY photo_id, user_id
ORDER BY user_id, photo_id
```

The result set is close to correct, so close that no one noticed it was wrong for a while.

If there's no data in table 2 (userviews), then the resulting row is correct.

However, if there is data there, the resultset is duplicating the count values from table 1, i.e.:

```
1082    3381    2012-05-25 08:50:20 3   3 <--WRONG, should be 1
1082    3387    2012-07-26 15:02:36 2   2 <--WRONG, should be 4
1117    3381    2012-05-23 03:46:02 1   0 <--CORRECT
1117    3382    2012-05-23 03:45:54 1   0 <--CORRECT
1117    3383    2012-05-23 03:45:09 1   0 <--CORRECT
```

Now, if this were SQL server, I'd just rewrite the damn thing using a CTE, but Mysql doesn't support a WITH clause, and I don't think I can subquery these as they return multiple values.

So how do I fix this in Mysql? Thanks in advance, I'm stumped on this one.

Comment: Can you post some sample data that is not aggregated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT p.user_id, p.photo_id, p.Photos, ph.date, v.Views
FROM photos ph,
      (SELECT p.user_id, p.photo_id, count(p.photo_id) as 'Photos'
      FROM photos p
      WHERE p.photo_id in ( 1,2,3 [...] )
      GROUP BY p.photo_id, p.user_id ) p,
     (SELECT v.user_id, v.photo_id, count(v.photo_id) as 'Views'
      FROM  userviews v
      WHERE v.photo_id in ( 1,2,3 [...] )
      GROUP BY v.photo_id, v.user_id 
      ) v
WHERE p.user_id = v.user_id AND 
      p.photo_id = v.photo_id AND
      ph.photo_id = p.photo_id AND
      ph.user_id = p.user_id
ORDER BY p.user_id, p.photo_id
```

EDIT Using left join

```
SELECT p.user_id, p.photo_id, p.Photos, ph.date, v.Views
FROM (SELECT v.user_id, v.photo_id, count(v.photo_id) as 'Views'
      FROM  userviews v
      WHERE v.photo_id in ( 1,2,3 [...] )
      GROUP BY v.photo_id, v.user_id 
      ) v left join (SELECT p.user_id, p.photo_id, count(p.photo_id) as 'Photos'
      FROM photos p
      WHERE p.photo_id in ( 1,2,3 [...] )
      GROUP BY p.photo_id, p.user_id ) p     
ON p.user_id = v.user_id AND p.photo_id = v.photo_id
      left join photos ph 
On ph.photo_id = p.photo_id AND
      ph.user_id = p.user_id
ORDER BY p.user_id, p.photo_id
```

When you do not GROUP BY or aggregate all the items in the SELECT list, MySQL chooses the values for the other columns and you might get unexpected results. ([REFER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)) that was the reason you were getting wrong results

Comment: Unfortunately, this only returns 1 row, the very first record.

Comment: Okay, that's closer...only issue now is that the where clause is too restrictive, it's simulating an inner join, I need a left outer.

Resultset jumps from id `1082` to `1612`, skipping over user `1117`, who correctly has photos & no views.

Comment: Ok you need left join for that.. Should I update code for you ?? or you will do it ??? :P

Comment: Remove that second left outer join in your example,and it's spot-on. Accepting, thank you for your help!